# Javascript method for parsing specific fields from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

What is the best method utilizing javascript to parse this JSON response:

```
{
    "records":[{
         "id":"recV4gf3nPUzO980w",
         "fields":{
            "truck name":"Darla's dumpling cart",
            "address":"150 W 57th St, New York, NY"
         },
         "createdTime":"2018-04-27T22:48:13.000Z"
    }]
}
```

So that only the "fields" data is returned, This is a representation of only one record in records and I need to create obj.records.fields where all fields are presented as an array.

Comment: `obj.records[0].fields`

Comment: I think it's important to be clear here that since this is already a JavaScript Object (at least in the code you posted), there's no need for parsing, just simple property access as @CertainPerformance demonstrated. If that entire code was a String type, then you'd need to use `JSON.parse(rawJsonString)` to make your object and then use property access.

Comment: Might be best to clear up what you've got by editing your question to either: `var obj = { ... }` or `var jsonString = "{ ... }"`.

Comment: You should also clarify if the array `records` will have more than one value. Do you want an array of the 'fields' objects or will there always only be one?

Comment: To answer Mark, yes records will be more then one, so data obj could be 10 records all structured the same way and I will need to loop through each for fields so obj.records[0].fields does give me the first field but obj.records[3].fields gives me the fourth listing I would like to have all fields as an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse response Json, then find the value as

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
var fields=obj.records[0].fields;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) can be used to get specific value:

```js
var fields, j = `{ "records":[{ "id":"recV4gf3nPUzO980w", "fields":{ "truck name":"Darla's dumpling cart", "address":"150 W 57th St, New York, NY" }, "createdTime":"2018-04-27T22:48:13.000Z" }] }`

JSON.parse(j, (key, value) => key === 'fields' ? (fields = value) : value)

console.log( fields )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript function `JSON.parse()` to convert text into a JavaScript object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

Make sure the text is written in JSON format, or else you will get a syntax error.